# Advanced optional routing in express

Tags: node.js, express, query-string, express-router

I'm Trying to build crud application using express and node.js

example query string

```
/table/?id=78&title=someTitle&code=3
```

where ID, Title And Code are optional. meaning:

- If none entered, return all rows.
- If id entered, return row that has that Id.
- If code and title entered, filter rows base on input.
- ...

But the **problem** is either I have to enter whole url string with null values, or the values mixed together, or express won't recognize my regex pattern (pattern is valid according to https://regexr.com website)

I've tried:

1. > https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/

   Route:

   ```
   /table/\??(id=)?:id?\&?(title=)?:title?\&?(code=)?:code?
   ```

   Path:

   ```
   /table/?id=78&title=someTitle&code=3
   ```

   Result:

   [image: Image About express routing result on express-route-tester website]
2. created my own regex:

   [image: my own regex]

   ```
   \/table\/\??(id=78)?\&?(title=someTitle)?\&?(code=3)?
   ```

   This will work unless I add optional express parameters.

#### Expected Result:

```
Path    
     /table/?id=78

request.params

    { id: '78'} 

---- 
Path
     /table/?code=3

request.params

    { code: '3' }

----
Path
    /table/?id=78&title=someTitle

request.params

    { id: '78', title: 'someTitle' }
```

PS: I *know* I can **achieve this with matching regular expression to request.url** But I want to know if there is any other way with express.

Comment: You could just use `req.query` to access the query string parameters, like `req.query.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### So Here's the answer:

I can achieve this by using `req.query` instead of `req.params`

#### req.query returns an object of inputs exactly like i wanted

Path

```
/table/?id=78&title=someTitle
```

request.query

```
{ id: '78', title: 'someTitle' }
```